# given natural number $n$ to find 4 distinct natural numbers $A,B,C,D$ $< n$ such that : $A+B+C+D=n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was hoping if it is possible for a given natural number $n$ to find 4 distinct natural numbers $A,B,C,D$ $< n$ such that :

$A+B+C+D=n$, and
{$\alpha_1A+\alpha_2B+\alpha_3C+\alpha_4D,\alpha_i\in$ {$ -1,0,1$}}$\supset${$1,2,...,n$}

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: search for partitions into distinct parts using Google

Answer (score 1):

In general, this won't be possible. Note that the set 
$$ S =  \bigl\{\alpha A + \beta B + \gamma C + \delta D\mid \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \in \{0,\pm 1\}\bigr\} $$
has at most $3^4= 81$ elements, contains $0$ and is symmetric with respect to 0. So $S$ can contain at most $40$ positive numbers.

---

Addendum: Let's try if we can realize the maximum, starting with $A = 1$, we have $\{-1,0,1\}$, if we add $B = 3$, this gives us $\{-4, \ldots, 4\}$, we let $C = 2(A + B) + 1 = 9$, giving $\{-13, \ldots, 13\}$ and finally $D = 2(A+B+C) + 1= 27$ does the job.

Comment: With the symmetry that I did see at first, the problem is impossible as stated (equality between sets).

Comment: so the question would make sense if I ask it for $n<=40$

Comment: @Mathematician Since the left hand side set contains always negative integers, it is impossible to get the equality between the two sets. But you may try to find $n$ such that $\left\{1,2,\cdots,n \right\}$ is included in your other set.

Comment: ah, yes i am sorry, let me edit this